# Ios filesharing without iTunes or an internet connection

Tags: ios, itunes, file-sharing

I am working on developing an enterprise application for ios 7 that needs to work offline and then sync with a desktop client (that I also need to write) for data transfer.

My company does not allow wireless or cell data in this area, and would strongly prefer to not use iTunes either.

The question is, how do you transfer data from an iPad over the usb cable to a custom windows program, without iTunes.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer would be: iExplorer (http://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/) plus some kind of a script to automate the data sync.

Otherwise, you can use the ExternalAccessory framework to communicate with the desktop via a USB tether. This would necessitate a desktop client running simultaneously to communicate with the device.

Answer (score 0):

peertalk (https://github.com/rsms/peertalk) does what you want, however the computer side library is only for mac os. Maybe you can port the protocol to windows by looking at that (the license is BSD)

Edit: [this guy](http://makezine.com/2013/04/22/peertalk-beaglebone-and-raspberry-pi/) managed to have it run under linux. It sits on [usbmuxd](https://github.com/libimobiledevice/usbmuxd), which also has a windows port, so it shouldn't be impossible.